# RegEx last space issue

Tags: javascript, regex

my RegEx = `/\s+/`

I want to accomplish that all digits are separated with spaces. It works, but it catches the last space too (Since i'm splitting it, last space goes as a "" array element).

"123 123 213" - works fine.

"21 12    21 421 " - catches last space.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Which language you were using over here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

trim the string before you run the regex and your done.

Comment: I do not know what language your using, but come languages have ltrim(rtrim( yourstring )) LEFT TRIM, RIGHT TRIM

Comment: javascript, it's mentioned above. Trim works properly, but empty string does not trims somehow.

Comment: Okay, got this. It had a value of " ". Now it fixed. Thanks for the solution!

Answer (score 1):

You may simply use word boundaries.

```
\b\s+\b
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/zJ7fC8/1)

Comment: It works, but it still reads the first space. I mean, if the string == " "

Comment: How? It won't be possible.

Comment: Will split nicely, but the trailing space remains. Try `"21 12 21 421 ".split(/\b\s+\b/)`

Comment: @EirikBirkeland ya, last space remains, think this is what op expected , not?

Answer (score 1):

Trim off any leading and trailing spaces, then split:

`var numArr = "21 12 21 421 ".replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "").split(/ +/);`

and that's it.

---

Depending on your environment, you can just use a built-in trim method instead.

`var numArr = "21 12 21 421 ".trim().split(" ");`

---

If you don't have trim, but want to use it, you can try this polyfill from [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim):

```
if (!String.prototype.trim) {
  String.prototype.trim = function () {
    return this.replace(/^[\s\uFEFF\xA0]+|[\s\uFEFF\xA0]+$/g, '');
  };
}
```

Comment: Hm... interestiong solution and it works properly except for 1 case. If we put a string like "     213 ___" - these last spaces are counting as elements.

Comment: Oops, forgot the g - try now. Without the global flag, it will only carry out the operation once. Also, it now splits on multiple spaces in between numbers if present: / +/

Answer (score 1):

Use this regex: `\s+(?=\S)` directly on the string, without the need of trim. *([demo](https://regex101.com/r/zJ7fC8/2))*

This matches any space that's followed by at least one character that's not a space.